# Difference between jest.fn(implementationCallback) and jest.fn().mockImplementation(implementationCallback)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest, ts-jest

I've noticed we got the same behavior when we jest.fn() with the implementation passed as param in the .fn() and jest.fn().mockImplementation(). If so, choosing the fit is jut a matter of tastes?

Example:

```
jest.fn((num1, num2) => num1 + num2)
// same as 
jest.fn().mockImplementation((num1, num2) => num1 + num2)
```

Does anyone have some thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`jest.fn(implementation)` is a shorthand for `jest.fn().mockImplementation(implementation)`

Not much to think about :)

Comment: As @k-wasilewski answered they are the same, jest.fn(implementation) is a shorthand. I did some digging and this is the code https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L930
Thanks!

Comment: For reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn